# Where is the NumPy version string documented?

Tags: python, numpy, version

What are the possible NumPy version strings? What is the standard?  Where is this documented?

```
1.4.0dev7059
1.4.0b1
1.4.0rc2
```

I've seen dev, b, rc.

Comment: What's unexpected about that? development build, beta 1, release candidate 2. Try the numpy mailing lists if you want specific information.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Thomas, the point is that if people are to parse the version string, then there should be some standard.  I want to know what the standard is.  John, that is all I want to know and the only problem I need to solve.

Answer (score 2):

`b`, `dev`, `rc` signify beta, development release and release candidate, respectively. Some of this is documented in the [Release Notes](http://www.scipy.org/ReleaseNotes/NumPy_1.0):

> Version Number explanation:
>
> 1.0.X will be maintainence releases (modules will not need  recompilation)
>
> 1.X will be major stable releases which might contain  changes to the
>   C-API and therefore might require
>   re-compilation of extension modules
>
> 1.0.1.dev3432 indicates SVN version 3432 of the development release 
>   leading up to 1.0.1
>
> 1.1.dev3532 indicates SVN version 3532 of the development release  leading up
>   to 1.1
>
> 1.0b2.dev2952 indicates SVN version 2952 of the development release 
>   leading up to the second beta release
>   of version 1.0

Also see the section titled "Version Numbering" in the [State of Scipy](http://conference.scipy.org/proceedings/SciPy2008/paper_1/full_text.pdf) (PDF) document, which specifies the `<major.minor.bugfix>` scheme.  (More generally, the wikipedia article on [Versioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versioning) may be useful.)